# bootstrap-carousel.tpl.php not used

Tags: theming

I have the bootstrap D7 Theme as a base themen. I added a new content-type for my header images and then create a bootstrap carousel using the bootstrap carousel view type.

Now I do get a carousel which seems to work fine but it looks crap, so I'd like to style it etc.

So accomplish this I though I could just "overload" bootstrap-carousel.tpl.php. But it doesn't work - it works for other template files though. Even worse: The original bootstrap-carousel.tpl seems to never be used. (Which porbably is the reason why my carousell looks totally unstyled).

What could be the reason for this?

Permission should be fine since it all the same and as I said, overloading other template files works.

Edit: For the carousel feature I use the bootstraps views module. I kind of expected that the tempalte files from the base theme kind of overwrite the ones from the module but it seems that isn't the case. why?

Answer (score 0):

Since the bootstrap carousel is based on a content type, you should be overriding node.tpl.php instead. Try dropping a node--bootstrap_carousel.tpl.php into your theme and making your markup changes there.

Comment: ok I'll try it .